# Filter dataframe on two interdependent columns

Tags: python, pandas, filter

We have a minimum example dataframe:

```
    data = [[1, 100],
            [1, 100],
            [2, 100],
            [2, 101],
            [3, 100],
            [4, 101],
            [4, 101]
           ]
    
    pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

I want to filter for col A where it is duplicated but only where col B is not duplicated for that subset.

For this dataframe the output I would expect is:

```
    [[2, 100],
     [2, 101]
    ]
```

I tried using a df.duplicated with other functions (making it easy to drop records like the single 3) but although I can meet the first part I'm not sure how to then do a windowed filter to further filter the data.

This is a minimum example but there are millions of records which is why i was looking for a vectorised solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
output = df[df['B'].groupby(df['A']).transform('nunique') > 1]
```

Comment: Found this one easier to follow so giving it the accepted answer. Both worked though - good solutions!

Comment: Probably `df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('nunique') > 1` will work, and it's even simpler :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `groupby` and `duplicated`:

```
filtered = df[df['A'].duplicated(keep=False) & df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: ~x.duplicated().any())]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
   A    B
2  2  100
3  2  101
```

Alternate solution:

```
filtered = df[df.groupby('A', as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g.apply(lambda col: col.duplicated(keep=False))).sum(axis=1) == 1]
```